# How to disable a file upload button for anonymous users?

Tags: ajax, files

I've created a commerce add to cart form with a file upload field. The user can use this to upload a logo but I don't want anonymous users to be able to do this. I can see that the file module uses ajax to handle the upload but I can't see how you can disable the upload button for non logged in users.

[image]

Comment: May be you could use some jquery and css to hide the button.

Comment: You may be right but unfortunately I don't know jquery so hoping for a drupal way to do this. May be there is an ajax validation callback or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module should help you achieve this.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>    field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
>
> Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned
>   based on what access the user has.
>
> Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on
>   who the entity owner is.
>
> Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead,
>   administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields
>   where this feature is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A directed `hook_form_alter` can be used to do this. Add to cart forms are special breed in that the form ID's include hashes for uniqueness, so you **can't** use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, string $form_id){
  // This will get all Add To Cart Forms. If you need something more specific, you'll have to tailor it for such.
  if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_') === 0) {
    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
      ... unset() the $form elements representing the upload stuff here.
      ... I would delete the file input and the upload button.
    }
  }
}
```